# Ninject.Web.Common throwing ActivationException trying to inject dependencies into HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, ninject.web

I'm not sure where to even begin solving this, but I'm getting an exception when trying to run my ASP.NET MVC app.

Here is the error I'm getting:

> [ActivationException: Error activating IntPtr
>
> No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>
> 1. Injection of dependency IntPtr into parameter method of constructor of type Func{IKernel}
> 2. Injection of dependency Func{IKernel} into parameter lazyKernel of constructor of type HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule
> 3. Request for IHttpModule
>
> Suggestions:
>
> 1. Ensure that you have defined a binding for IntPtr.
> 2. If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
> 3. Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
> 4. If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
> 5. If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 359
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:line 197
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:line 165
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 114
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 96
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 96
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:line 157
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 386
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:line 197
   at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:line 165
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 114
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 96
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 96
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:line 157
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 386
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\NinjectHttpModule.cs:line 41
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
```

This doesn't seem to be an error everyone is getting (at least, my Google searches haven't turned up anything usefuL), so I assume I'm doing something odd, but I have no idea where to begin debugging this.

I should mention that I'm using several Ninject libraries (Ninject, Ninject.Web.Common, Ninject.MVC3, and Ninject.FluentValidation), all of which are version 3.0.00-RC3. I realize that all bets are off if I use pre-release libraries, but I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong because others don't seem to be getting the same error.

Any thoughts on what the problem could be or where I should start looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to delete my App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs file (which was created when I installed Ninject.MVC 3.0.0-rc2) and reinstall the Nuget package (rc3). The newly created NinjectWebCommon.cs file was slightly different. Problem solved!

Comment: I faced the same problem with a WebApi project, debuging I noticed that the CreateKernel in App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs was called twice, and the second time it crashes, I fixed removing 2 lines at the very top of that file

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(RetailStore.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(RetailStore.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

And then the method was called once and the bug vanished.

Answer (score 10):

You can fix this by adding these two bindings to the kernel:

```
kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
```

Comment: This removed the error on my mvc app, but the routes started throwing exceptions about resource not found.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem with a WebApi project, debuging I noticed that the CreateKernel in App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs was called twice, and the second time it crashes, I fixed removing 2 lines at the very top of that file

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(RetailStore.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(RetailStore.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
```

And then the method was called once and the bug vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error message, even though the code hadn't changed from the night before. 
I was working through the example code from http://www.asp.net/web-api/videos/getting-started/authorization

I lost well over an hour over something silly. I had decorated my controller to [Authorize], but the next day when I started work and was testing the api, my session was no longer valid, so I assumed it was something subtle in the code that had changed.

Hope this helps someone else who is as new to Ninject as I am...

What appeared in my browser was: 

`XML Parsing Error: no element found

Location: server-name/api/Cities/

Line Number 1, Column 1:`